# Typescript HOC with React.createContext

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-context

I have this .js snippet that I need to translate into Typescript.

```
import React from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null)

export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
    <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
        {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
    </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
)

export default FirebaseContext
```

my best guess is

```
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null)

export const withFirebase = (Component: React.ComponentClass) => (props: any) => (
    <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
        {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
    </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
)
```

but when I try to use the context – by passing a `new Firebase()`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import App from './components/App';
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase';

ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
        <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);

serviceWorker.unregister()
```

in this case – I get `Type 'Firebase' is not assignable to type 'null'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have not specified any type to `createContext`. Adding a Firebase type to it should work

```
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext<Firebase | null>(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even better is to create type and use Partial for default values:

```
type FirebaseContextProps = {
  firebase: Firebase
  isOk: boolean
  data: string
}

const FirebaseContext= React.createContext<Partial<FirebaseContextProps>>({})

<FirebaseContext.Provider value={{ firebase, isOk, data }}>
```